# I am not able to find mistake in my solution of the finding $\displaystyle\lim _{h\to 0} \frac{q(1-\cos h )}{4 h^{2}}$, where $q\not=0 $.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the value of $$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{q(1-\cos h )}{4 h^{2}}$$where $q$ is a non-zero constant.

Now in the book the answer is $\dfrac{q}{8}$. You can see the steps at [this site](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/calculus-1/limit-calculator/?f=q%281-%20cos%20%28x%29%29%2F%284x%5E2%29&var=x&val=0&dir=&steps=on).

This answer is different from my answer, but I am not able to find where I have done the mistake(s).

My steps are:
$$\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{q(1-\cos h)}{4 h^{2}}=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{q}{4 h} \times \frac{1-\cos h}{h}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{q}{4 h}  \times \lim _{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos h}{h}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{q}{4 h} \times 0 
=0$$

Comment: Begin by drawing the uninteresting factor $\frac q4$ from the expression.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{1-\cos h}h$ tends to zero ??

Comment: @Yves Daoust By Product law of limits, the law states ${\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[ {f\left( x \right)g\left( x \right)} \right] }={ \lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right) \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to a} g\left( x \right)}$ only if both functions tends to finite number.

Comment: I am not sure you understood my question. This is a quotient, not a product.

Comment: @Yves Daoust I really don't understand your question. Maybe you are asking for proof of   $ \lim_{x \mathop \to 0} \frac {\cos x - 1} x = 0$. If you are asking for it than go to this site: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_(Cosine_(X)_-_1)_over_X

Comment: Yes I am asking how you knew that. Because those who know the limit of $\frac{1-\cos h}h$ also know that of $\frac{1-\cos h}{h^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one function tends to $0$ and another one is tending to $\infty$ (or is unbounded) you cannot say that the prodct tends to $0$. It is like saying $1=\lim_{x \to 0}1=_{x \to 0} [x (\frac 1 x)]= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac   1 x \lim_{x \to 0} x=(\lim \frac 1 x) (0) =0$. Do you see why  this argument doesn't work?

Limit of  a product is the product of the limits when both limits are finite. Do not use this when one of the factors does not have a finite limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if two functions are in multiplication and if one function tends to $0$ and other to any number then I can proceed as I did in my solution?

Comment: I have already answered that question now. See my edit. @HiterDean

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$q\dfrac{1-\cos ^2 h}{(1+\cos h)(4h^2)}=$

$\dfrac {\sin^2 h}{h^2}\dfrac {q}{4(1+\cos h)}.$

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a mistake by concluding that the product tends to zero, when one function goes to infinity and the other to zero. Why don't you try it this way:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{q(1-\cos h)}{4h^2}$$
We can write $\cos h= 1-2\sin^2\frac{h}{2}$ so $1-\cos h =2\sin^2\frac{h}{2}$

So, the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2q\sin^2\frac{h}{2}}{4h^2}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2q\sin^2\frac{h}{2}}{4\frac{h^2}{4}.4}$$

W.K.T. $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, which we can also extend as $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}=1$
Thus,
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2q\sin^2 \frac{h}{2}}{4\frac{h^2}{4}.4}=\frac{2q}{16}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin^2\frac{h}{2}}{\frac{h^2}{4}}=\frac{2q}{16} =  \frac{q}{8}$$

Comment: Consider using ```\cos h``` instead of ```\cosh``` next time. $\cos$ and $\cosh$ are two entirely different functions.

Comment: +1, I was going to write the same (Peter's answer is basically this but even more simpler). Minor nitpick: Write `\cos h` instead of `\cosh`, the latter is the notation for hyperbolic cosine.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, missed it in a hurry

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is that you have to use I'Hospital's Rule twice. Here is my attempt at solving the question.

We know that $\lim_{h \to 0} c f{\left(h \right)} = c \lim_{h \to 0} f{\left(h \right)}$ with $c= \frac{q}{4}$ and $f{\left(h \right)} = \frac{1 - \cos{\left(h \right)}}{h^{2}}$. Therefore, we can take out the constant so that we can focus on the variable $h$. Since $q$ is treated as a constant, we can take it and $4$ out. This step looks like this:

\begin{align}
{\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{q \left(1 - \cos{\left(h \right)}\right)}{4 h^{2}}} &= {\left(\frac{q \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos{\left(h \right)}}{h^{2}}}{4}\right)}  \\
&= \frac{q}{4} \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(h)}{h^2}\end{align}

Here we have to use l'Hopital's Rule because we have the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Therefore:

\begin{align}
\frac{q \cdot {\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos{\left(h \right)}}{h^{2}}}}{4} &= \frac{q  \cdot {\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dh}\left(1 - \cos{\left(h \right)}\right)}{\frac{d}{dh}\left(h^{2}\right)}}}{4} \\
&= \frac{q \cdot {\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin{\left(h \right)}}{2 h}}}{4}
\end{align}

By using the rule mentioned in the third line, you can take out the constants and focus in on the variable $h$. We have to once again use I'Hospital's Rule because of the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$:

\begin{align}
\frac{q \cdot {\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin{\left(h \right)}}{2 h}}}{4} &= \frac{q \cdot{\left(\frac{\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin{\left(h \right)}}{h}}{2}\right)}}{4} \\
&\stackrel{\text{I'Hopital}}= \frac{q \cdot{\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dh}\left(\sin{\left(h \right)}\right)}{\frac{d}{dh}\left(h\right)}}}{8} \\
&= \frac{q \cdot{\lim_{h \to 0} \cos{\left(h \right)}}}{8} \\
&= \frac{q \cdot 1}{8} \\
&= \frac{q}{8}
\end{align}

Comment: Where does this answer mention the "answer to the OP's question"? He asked for the mistake(s) in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You're making the mistake of equating $\infty\times0$ to $0$. You have to work the standard way of handling the indeterminate forms, usually converting into $0/0$ and using L'Hôpital's Rule.